# TypeScript: Parameters to modify Interfaces

Tags: typescript

As of now, i have these simplified interfaces, which i combine to create many different types:

```
interface MyObject {
    values: {
        [1]: number,
    }
}

interface MyOtherObject {
    values: {
        [2]: number,
    }
}

export type MyObjectType = MyObject & MyOtherObject & {};
```

My project will eventually be very great in size, and therefore i want to create a good interface/type system which will help me create objects with many elements. I found myself needing the following feature:

Is it possible to have parameters to interfaces? Specifically, i want to reserve keys to objects parameters. Below i have given an example (it does not work):

```
interface MyObject<index> {
    values: {
        [index]: number,
    }
}

export type MyFirstObjectType = MyObject<1> & MyObject<2> {};
export type MySecondObjectType = MyObject<1> & MyObject<3> {};

let newObject: MyFirstObjectType = {
    values: {
        [1]: 5,
        [2]: 3,
        // [3]: 5, this should not be possible in "MyFirstObjectType", but possible in "MySecondObjectType"
    }
}
```

This might be a crazy idea, but i'll throw the question out anyways, maybe i learn something new. It could also very well be i should think out some other system that does not involve this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that crazy, just use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
interface MyObject<index extends number> {
    values: {
        [K in index]: number;
    }
}
```